# How to debug pac file in chrome without alert function?

Tags: proxy, google-chrome, pac

I recently experienced a problem with a new pac file with chrome, (same pac file with IE and Firefox works).

I supposed that my problem is due to `myIpAddress()` function, [see this  post](https://serverfault.com/questions/691360/proxy-pac-file-ipv6-with-myadresse), which do not return my main ip address.

I would like to make some tests to debug pac file, but [according to this post](http://findproxyforurl.com/debug-pac-file/), debug function is no longer supported.

I also tried to use [some options from this post](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/debugging-net-proxy).

In the `chrome://net-internals/#proxy` tab, I see which pac file is used, but nothing more.

And with the `chrome://net-internals/#events` tab, I see each request, but when I filter events with `PROXY_SCRIPT_DECIDER`, it returns no events.

I think my problem is related to `myIpAddress`, so how to test `myIpAddress` function, and is there a way to debug pac file without `alert()` ?

Answer (score 8):

I didn't find the information anywhere, but chrome shows alert in `chrome://net-internals/#events` tab with description : `PAC_JAVASCRIPT_ALERT`.

Also you can find what chrome use as proxy in tab : `chrome://net-internals/#proxy`

Comment: Unfortunately this is no longer that easy (at least in Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98)

Comment: How to debug, now that `net-internals/#events` is removed?

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020, I'd do it with:

```
chrome://net-export/
```

and it's companion [netlog-viewer](https://netlog-viewer.appspot.com/) to browse the information.

Answer (score 0):

tested on Edge 108.0.1462.46, debug pac on SwitchyOmega plugin.

1. enable pac proxy with some alert statement on SwitchyOmega
2. open web page "edge://net-export/", start logging
3. open some web page
4. stop logging on net-export
5. open https://netlog-viewer.appspot.com/ , choose the log file, upload, then
   click Events on left side, search event "PAC_JAVASCRIPT_ALERT", see your alter log

Answer (score -1):

You can try out https://github.com/MamoruAsagami/PacTestBench.
You need Java runtime environment in to run it, however.

Comment: It requires -myIpAddress as a parameter, so it can't be used for debugging that feature. Plus, it only seems to be able to test whether the right proxy string is returned. That's less helpful than logging internal variable values.